# Difficult limit: $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3/2} \int _0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

I found this question online

> Find the limit:$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3/2} \int _0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}dx $$

I've been told that I need to use the gamma function by converting $n^{3/2}=n\sqrt{n}$ and doing $u$ sub $u=x\sqrt{n}\rightarrow du=\sqrt{n} dx$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3/2} \int _0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}dx =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int _0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{nx^2\sqrt{n}}{(x^2+1)^n}dx =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int _0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{u^2}{(\frac{u^2}{n}+1)^n}dx
$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \int _0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{u^2}{(\frac{u^2}{n}+1)^n}dx
$$

How does one proceed from here to get the gamma function?

Comment: Use the fact that $(1+\frac z n)^n \rightarrow e^z$ and use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: your bounds are incorrect after the variable change

Comment: $$I_n= n^{3/2}\int^1_0\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\,dx\stackrel{u=\sqrt{n}x}{=}n^{3/2}\int^{\sqrt{n}}_0\frac{u}{n\Big(1+\tfrac{u^2}{n}\Big)^n}\frac{du}{\sqrt{n}}=\int^\sqrt{n}_0\frac{u^2}{\Big(1+\tfrac{u^2}{n}\Big)^n}\,du$$
As $x\mapsto \big(1+\tfrac1x\Big)^x$ is monotone increasing on $(0,\infty)$,  $$ \Big(1+\tfrac{u^2}{n}\Big)^n\geq \Big(1+\tfrac{u^2}{2}\Big)^2$$ 
$$\frac{u^2}{\Big(1+\tfrac{u^2}{n}\Big)^n}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\sqrt{n}]}(u)\leq \frac{4u^2}{(2+u^2)^2}\in L_1((0,\infty))$$
Then, by dominated convergence 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_n=\int^\infty_0u^2 e^{-u^2}\,du=\sqrt{\pi}/4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the inequalities $x^2-\frac12 x^4\le \log(1+x^2)\le x^2$, we find that

$$\int_0^1 x^2e^{-nx^2}e^{-nx^4/2}\,dx\le \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\,dx\le \int_0^1 x^2e^{-nx^2}\,dx\tag1$$

Then, enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x/\sqrt n$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$\frac1{n^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt n} x^2e^{-x^2}e^{-x^4/2n}\,dx\le \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\,dx\le \frac1{n^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt n} x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx\tag2$$

Finally, multiplying $(2)$ by $n^{3/2}$, letting $n\to \infty$, and applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2} \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_0^{n^{1/2}}\frac{u^2}{(1+n^{-1}u^2)^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}u \overset{n\to\infty}{⟶} \int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\overset{t=u^2}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty t^{1/2} e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t= \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{2} = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$